# SharePoint Online send Email based on a date

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, reminder

I`m trying to create a workflow that automatically sends reminders based on a date column in a list on SharePoint Online.

E.g.: if 1st Reminder date = today, then send the reminder after 2 days

2nd Reminder date = today, send reminder after 5 days

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pause function

If first day != today
   pause untill date = First day
   pause time 2 days
   send email

Try using something like this

Answer (score 0):

i created example in SharePoint Workflow 2010. They are linear actions I hope you mean that this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used a number of workflow based approaches but somehow there is always this or that requirement that can't be fullfilled (at least I can't figur it out).
So these days I have reverted to using timer jobs for the purpose, either powershell or C#.
Use a search query to get the content, and iterate through each item looking for the proper criteria, like those where the reminder date is less than today +30 and RemindSentDate (a field on the list or in another list) is empty or more that x days old. Another check could be to varify that the receiver of the notification is valid, and send the notification to somebody else if that is not the case